# Why bootstarop calendar doesn't change date on Calendar box

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I have a bootstrap-date picker, I call a function to change the date of the input and the calendar box, the input changes the box isn't and when it loses focus the input changes to the (wrong) calendar date. I need to know how to change dynamically both calendar box and calendar input
//Html

```
<div id="positionHelper">
    <a id="anotherDatelink" style="float:left"  class="pull-left" href="#" onclick="reset()">resetsate</a>
    <div id="container" style="padding-left:120px">
        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input  type="text" class="form-control  @semanticClass" 
          name="@Model.Name" id="@Model.Id" title="@Model.Name" value="@val">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//js

```
  function reset() {
                 var today = getToday();
//works and changes the input line


    $("#container").find("input").val(today);


**nothing here worked.**            

 // $('.datepicker-days').datepicker('setDate', null);-this class is from bootstrap 
            // $("#container").datepicker('setDate', null);
            // $('#container').data('datepicker').setDate(null);                                                
            //$('#container').datepicker('setDate', new Date(2019, 11, 24));
            //$('#container').datepicker('update');
            // $('#container').val('');
           // $("#container").click(function(){ $(this).datepicker("setDate", today )});
            //$('container').data("DateTimePicker").date("08/08/2019");
           //  $(".datepicker").datepicker("update", "08/08/2019");
          //  $("#container").datepicker("setDate", new Date());           
           //         $("#container").datepicker()
          //  .on("changeDate", function (e) {
         //       alert(e);
          // });
        //
```

//I added a picture to show the differences - the calendar box (15/06/2017 should be -> 25/05/2017)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hey here is an example how you can do it
HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Select time</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimestart">                                           
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" name="datetimestart" type="text">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

javascript :

```
$('#datetimestart').datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
        defaultDate: moment()
});
```

call this snippet in the document ready function (create a new file main.js).

create a folder with all needed JavaScript-libs and include them at the head of your HTML-DOC:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

The bootstrap.min.js is not really needed for the picker, but is also used in the HTML-doc.
Which datetimepicker do you use? I recommend you this library https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/